# JavaFX TreeView: Is it possible to add TreeItems to TreeView which are subclasses of the root?

Tags: javafx

I'm wondering if it's possible to add such treeitems to TreeView which are subclasses of the root?

Like this way..

```
TreeView<Human> tree = new TreeView<>();

Student student = new Student();
TreeItem<Student> studentItem = new TreeItem<>(student);

Human human = new Human();
TreeItem<Human> root = new TreeItem<>(human);

root.getChildren().add(studentItem);

tree.setRoot(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add `TreeItem`s to `TreeView` which are subclasses of the root?

Yes, absolutely. However `TreeItem<Student>` is not a subclass of `TreeItem<Human>`, since the parameters don't match.

The following would compile:

```
Student student = new Student();
TreeItem<Human> studentItem = new TreeItem<>(student);
...
root.getChildren().add(studentItem);
```

And so would the following:

```
Student student = new Student();
TreeItem<Student> studentItem = new TreeItem<>(student);
...
root.getChildren().add((TreeItem) studentItem);
```

**A note on the latter code snippet:** It's safe to use `TreeItem<Student>` as `TreeItem<Human>`, however this kind of casting should be avoided in general, since it circumvents the type checks for the type arguments done by the compiler.